Secure connection to ALB results in "Blocked loading mixed active content"
I have configured my domain to point to my ALB. When I navigate to my domain it's failing to load and the console show's this error:
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://my-app.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/"

My SSL certificate is for my domain, I did not include my ALB DNS in the certificate. I have configured my ALB to forward HTTP traffic to HTTPS. My app is built on Next-JS. I don't have any 'http://' requests hard coded into the application code. Is this likely to be a bug inside my application code anyway? Or is it likely the ALB configuration itself?
EDIT: It looks like the request to my ALB is over http and not https. I can't figure out why that is. I've configured the route53 record to point to the ALB.
